# java characters encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am searching for Lithuanian characters encoding. I found these: IBM775, IBM921. But in Java name they are like Cp775 and Cp921. But when I use it in app it doesn't work. Are they correct ones?

**EDITED**
Mysql database has UTF encoding. I tried it too but it doesn't work. I am getting null in the places where words with lithuanian characters should be.

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases)

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and spend one or two days to understand Unicode. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do that does not work?

Comment: Can't you keep the encoding as UTF-8 itself? I don't think the others will work if UTF-8 doesn't work. Somewhere in the flow it is getting converted to an incompatible encoding. Try to find that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the encoding `ISO-8859-4` or `Cp1112`.

Here the official java page of [supported encondings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).

And here the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) where you can get a complete list with description.